# double type object (characters and numbers) to dataframe

Tags: r

I want to create a dataframe (in order to filter) from a "double" object which contains both character and numbers.
My code:

````
  select(Tick,Date,Return) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Tick,values_from = Return) %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% 
  colMeans()*100```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is a `named` vector.  We can `stack` it to create a data.frame with two columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
select(Tick,Date,Return) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Tick,values_from = Return) %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% 
  {colMeans(.)*100} %>%
  stack
```

---

Or use `pivot_longer`

```
select(Tick,Date,Return) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Tick,values_from = Return) %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% 
  {colMeans(.)*100 }%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything())
```

Comment: for the first option I get this error {'Error in data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0' }and for the second one I get this { 'Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')" '}

Comment: awesome!! could you tell me how the curly brackets are used?

Comment: @Pro23 it is just that you are doing two operations `colMeans` and multiplications.  So with `{}`, it blocks it before executing the next

Comment: Thank you.! It was really helpful.